# Conditional Expectation and constant values

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm catching up on my Probability Theory 2 notes, and I'm stuck on this one statement, which is probably very trivial, so I apologize if my question lacks any challenge. It's Example 34.1 from Billingsley, dealing with conditional expectation. Here is my question:

Let $B_{1},B_{2},\ldots$ be a finite or countable partition on $\Omega$ generating the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{G}$. Then $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ must, since it is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, have some *constant value* over $B_{i}$. Why? Why is it a constant value?

I'm having a hard time differentiating between $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is as defined above versus $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(Y)$, where $Y$ is a random variable, versus what undergraduate courses teach, in that $E[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Expectations should be constant since the number of occurrences in $B_i$ is fixed

Comment: Just to be clear $E[X|B_{1}]$, say, will shoot out a number because we know where our $\omega$s lie. What about $E[X|\sigma(Y)$, $Y$ a random variable? The reason for my confusion is because in undergrad probability courses, $E[X|Y]$ was a function of $Y$.

Comment: "the number of occurrences in Bi is fixed" The number of occurences of what?